# With icicle-locate-file, how can I find all *.txt files in the directory?

Tags: find-file, icicles

I need to find all `*.txt` files in the directory, like

```
find ./ -iname "*txt"
```

I wanted an Emacs solution, so I found the [multi-command](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands) `icicle-locate-file-other-window`.

Its documentation tells me to type a multi-completion pattern to match

```
f.* C-M-j some text .* in the file
```

Nothing happens when I press `C-M-j`. What command is this bound to?

I also know about `find-name-dired`, but I want to try this Icicles thingy ;).

Answer (score 1):

`icicle-locate-file(-other-window)` allows (but doesn't require) [multi-completion](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Completions) input matching.

In your example you apparently just want to find all files whose ''names'' match `*.txt`, so you don't provide a second pattern, to match file content, at all. You just type `.*\.txt S-TAB`, that is, a regexp matching the file name, followed by `S-TAB` for apropos (regexp-matching) completion.

But if you ''do'' want to also match file ''content'' then you use `C-M-j` to tell Icicles that your first, file-name-matching pattern is finished and you next will type a file-content-matching pattern.

(Unless you've set option `icicle-show-Completions-initially-flag` to non-`nil`, you need to tell Emacs to show completions, at least initially, using `TAB` or `S-TAB`. And if you do want to match more than just the first part then use `S-TAB`.)

To match multiple parts, you use `C-M-j` after each input pattern for a part. What that does is insert a string that separates the patterns - ''nothing more''. (`C-M-j` is bound during minibuffer completion to command `icicle-insert-list-join-string`.)

By default, the separator string is the two chars `^G` (Control G) followed by `^J` (Control J, aka ''newline''). You could enter the string chars yourself, if you wanted, instead of using `C-M-j` -- to insert a Control-G char you need to use `C-q C-g`. (In Icicles, `C-j`/newline is self-inserting.)

This odd separator string is the default because (1) the newline char gives you a new minibuffer line for each pattern and (2) it's very unlikely that any of your patterns will contain such a string. (You don't see the `^G` character because it's hidden.) Contrast this with completion frameworks that use `SPC`, which doesn't let you use space chars in patterns. You can customize the separator string, using option `icicle-list-join-string`. (And some Icicles commands, such as `icicle-search`, bind it to a simpler string, such as `"^I"` (just a TAB char) or `": "`.

[This part](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#MultiCompletion) of the Nutshell View of Icicles gives a simple overview of using multicompletion. [This topic](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Completions) presents multicompletion in detail. [This topic](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input#ReadingFileNames) tells you about commands, such as `icicle-locate-file`, that read file names. And [this topic](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input#MatchFileContent) tells you about using multicompletion with such commands, to match both file names and file content.